# Why don't we use wireless electricity today?

Tags: power-supply, wireless

I was reading about Nikola Tesla today (via [the Oatmeal](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/tesla)) and read about the Wardenclyffe Tower which (among other things) was intended to transmit electricity wirelessly. Forgive the naivety of the question, but if technology that could transmit electrical current wirelessly was invented over 100 years ago, why don't we use wireless electricity in our day to day lives today? In other words, why do we have to physically plug in our electrical devices (phones/computer, etc) if there exist such a thing as wireless electricity? If its an issue of efficiency/cost then I would imagine that some rich people still wouldn't mind paying extra, in light of the waste, for the added convenience.

Please explain in layman's terms (though a simple answer would suffice).

Comment: If the power company distributed wireless electricity, it would be much harder to meter the usage from each customer, or prevent non-customers from setting up an antenna and using the service without paying.

Comment: Don't believe everything you read on the Oatmeal.

Comment: So is your answer, it's possible, but you can't monitize it effectively, so nobody is selling it? If thats the case, I would assume somebody would have created some at home adapter/router which would allow you to wireless share electricity within a certain range (though unable to protect from your neighbor stealing the "weaker" current)

Comment: @ThePhoton: It would just be a non-excludable good, and could be paid for with taxes like any other.  That doesn't say anything about whether it's feasible or not.  I've yet to see a good explanation showing that Tesla's worldwide power idea would even work.  Just because someone thought of something doesn't make it viable.

Comment: @endolith, We could go down a rabbit hole discussing your point, but I think there's very few governments out there that have a good track record of managing infrastructure like electric distribution without either underfunding infrastructure, or overspending on boondoggle projects.

Comment: Nobody has been able to make it work cost effectively over any substantial distance. Much that Tesla did was great - but not everything. Even if t he worst case conspiracy theories were true, which they aren't, some  people would do this if they could because it makes sense to do so technically if it can be done cost effectively. I  had personal experience of short range application of people doing this 40 years ago (literally) over very short distances. It was "lost" when the professor doing it died and people lost interest, reintroduced by a student of the prof and formed the basis of ...\

Comment: ... modern IPT (inductive power transfer ) for industry. Look for patents in Nw zealand for Professor Don Otto from about 1970-1975? period. No magic. Just well known engineering. But not Tesla's range either.

Comment: Mass wireless power transmission is certainly the way of the future. I have read several articles detailing systems which could transmit power generated from large solar arrays in low Earth orbit, and the Moon. Tesla is my favorite scientist by the way! As Kyle explained below, wireless power transmission *is* used today in consumer technology - just not the way Tesla envisioned.

Comment: I always thought that the main reason this stuff (pure electric, non magnetic) never took off was if you get your hand in the middle of the circuit it would hurt. A lot. What kind of "electricity" did Tesla envision? ELF-ULF?

Comment: I have a friend who set up wireless electricity at his house. It works great and he hasn't had a problem with it. I am going to try it myself this spring and see how it works out.

Comment: @capcom: That is very different from Tesla's idea of broadcasting power like we broadcast radio signals.  Significant power can be transmitted with EM waves, like from solar power satellites.  One of the issus is to keep the beam narrow so that the collector can be small, power isn't wasted, and the exclusion zone where nobody is allowed else they get hurt is economically manageable.  Many element phased arrays with short wavelength (microwaves) can achieve possibly useful levels of this, but again, this is not at all what Tesla tried to do that the OP is asking about.

Comment: @endolith "Don't believe everything you read on the (Oatmeal) *Internet*." :-)

Comment: I would never use wireless technology. Some people prefer wires you know. Once I heard that a computer started on fire when they turned it on. They stopped the fire by pulling the plug. If its power was wireless the whole house could have burned down.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I use wireless electricity everyday.

In my toothbrush:

[image: toothbrush]

And in my cell phone:

[image: qi phone]

The method used in my devices is called [Inductive Charging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_charging). I talk a bit more about it in my answer to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36767/do-magnetics-connectors-exist/36853#36853). This is the most common and most practical form of transmitting energy wirelessly at the moment. But as many of the comments have noted, this is considered near field transmission. And with an effective range of only a few millimeters, it is *very* near field.

The [amount of energy transferred and the efficiency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonant_inductive_coupling#Energy_transfer_and_efficiency) of the transfer can be increased quite a bit (although still considered to be near field) by adding a capacitor to each of the inductor coils and tuning the resultant RLC networks to have a high Q factor at the same (resonant) frequency. A team from MIT did research into using [inductive resonance](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/everyday-tech/wireless-power2.htm) as a wireless power transfer system.

[image: resonant induction recharging]

The researchers have since formed a company called [WiTricity](http://www.witricity.com/pages/technology.html) to further develop the technology. While they still haven't brought a product to the commercial market, they have made some impressive [demonstrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiTricity):

> The term WiTricity was used for a project that took place at MIT, led
> by Marin Soljačić in 2007. The MIT researchers successfully
> demonstrated the ability to power a 60 watt light bulb wirelessly,
> using two 5-turn copper coils of 60 cm (24 in) diameter, that were 2 m
> (7 ft) away, at roughly 45% efficiency. The coils were designed to
> resonate together at 9.9 MHz (≈ wavelength 30 m) and were oriented
> along the same axis. One was connected inductively to a power source,
> and the other one to a bulb. The setup powered the bulb on, even when
> the direct line of sight was blocked using a wooden panel. Researchers
> were able to power a 60 watt light bulb at roughly 90% efficiency at a
> distance of 3 feet. The research project was spun off into a private
> company, also called WiTricity.

It's important to note that the distance between the transmitter and the receiver plays a crucial factor in determining how much energy can reliably be transferred. As can be seen in [this paper](http://www.cornellcollege.edu/physics/files/mandip-sibakoti.pdf) based on the MIT project, the decay in voltage with respect to distance between the coils is exponential:

[image: exponential decay]

But there are many [other methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_energy_transfer) such as microwave and laser that are capable of much greater distances. However, these methods are very directional and so are applicable over a much smaller area than Tesla's proposed Wardenclyffe Tower which would be omnidirectional. There are also many other factors to consider when implementing one of these methods:

> ## Microwave:
>
> Power transmission via radio waves can be made more directional,
> allowing longer distance power beaming, with shorter wavelengths of
> electromagnetic radiation, typically in the microwave range. A
> rectenna may be used to convert the microwave energy back into
> electricity. Rectenna conversion efficiencies exceeding 95% have been
> realized. Power beaming using microwaves has been proposed for the
> transmission of energy from orbiting solar power satellites to Earth
> and the beaming of power to spacecraft leaving orbit has been
> considered.
> ...
> For earthbound applications a large area 10 km diameter receiving
> array allows large total power levels to be used while operating at
> the low power density suggested for human electromagnetic exposure
> safety. A human safe power density of 1 mW/cm2 distributed across a 10
> km diameter area corresponds to 750 megawatts total power level. This
> is the power level found in many modern electric power plants.
> ...
> Wireless high power transmission using microwaves is well proven.
> Experiments in the tens of kilowatts have been performed at Goldstone
> in California in 1975 and more recently (1997) at Grand Bassin on
> Reunion Island. These methods achieve distances on the order of a
> kilometer.
>
> ## Laser
>
> Advantages of laser based energy transfer compared with other wireless
> methods are:
>
> 1. collimated monochromatic wavefront propagation allows narrow beam cross-section area for energy transmission over large ranges.
> 2. compact size of solid state lasers-photovoltaics semiconductor diodes fit into small products.
> 3. no radio-frequency interference to existing radio communication such as Wi-Fi and cell phones.
> 4. control of access; only receivers illuminated by the laser receive power.
>
> Its drawbacks are:
>
> 1. Laser radiation is hazardous, even at low power levels it can blind people and animals, and at high power levels it can kill through
>    localized spot heating
> 2. Conversion to light, such as with a laser, is inefficient
> 3. Conversion back into electricity is inefficient, with photovoltaic cells achieving 40%–50% efficiency. (Note that conversion efficiency
>    is rather higher with monochromatic light than with insolation of
>    solar panels).
> 4. Atmospheric absorption, and absorption and scattering by clouds, fog, rain, etc., causes losses, which can be as high as 100% loss
> 5. As with microwave beaming, this method requires a direct line of sight with the target.

And of course there is the "disturbed charge of ground and air" method used by Tesla. As far as the Tesla system goes, that got shut down because [funding ran out and the stock market crashed](http://www.damninteresting.com/teslas-tower-of-power/). As for why it's not been tried since, it's primarily because such a system could not be strictly metered. Therefore, the power companies could not charge per usage and make lots of money. Without a way to monetize the technology, no investment into research and development will ever be made. That's the (conspiracy) theory, anyways. Although there are [many other reasons](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/934/whats-up-with-broadcast-power) why this method is either unfeasible or just outright wouldn't work.

I couldn't find an article with definitive numbers as to efficiency. But it's my guess that efficiency is the main reason you do not see this technology in more wide spread usage. However, it does exist, people like me (read: not rich) do have access to it, and it works quite well.

**Edit:**

I found a [case study](http://www.wirelesspowerconsortium.com/technology/comparison-of-power-savings.html) done by the Wireless Power Consortium, makers of qi charger for my phone, which states (emphasis mine):

> In this section we compare the total power consumption in a 5-year
> period
>
> Case Study:
>
> Average system efficiency of **wireless** charger N *sys-wireless* = 0.50 (50%)
>
> Average system efficiency of **wired** power adapter N *sys-wired* = 0.72 (72%)
> Assume that the average charging power is 2W.

So the wired part of their system has an efficiency of 72% and the wireless part has an efficiency of 50%. That is using an inductive method where the coils are a few millimeters apart. Compare that to the WiTricity from Joel which states an efficiency of 40% over 2 meters.

Factor in the additional costs associated with the extra circuity and components for a wireless system as compared to the cost of a length of copper wire and you can see why long distance wireless energy transfer is still considered impractical for mass market use.

Comment: Possibly relevant link to go with your answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiTricity, it's a third form of energy transfer that relies on the reactive near-field response (not inductive, yet not radiative).

Comment: No no. Tesla did not mean magnetic coupling. He meant that the very ELECTRICITY goes through the air .. Over .. unlimited distance ! Thanks to him, he never finished the project.

Comment: So in terms of longer distances (say 10 yards) there are laser, microwave, inductive resonance, and resonant energy transfer methods (among others) which could in theory 'transfer the power' to where it needs to go, but at this point all of the methods are so inefficient that they are deemed impractical. Is my understanding correct? 

The WiTricity article @JoelCornett referenced seems promising (citing a study of lighting a 60 watt light bulb at roughly 90% efficiency at a distance of 3 feet) though unfortunately, there is no citation on that part.

Comment: @Droid: Here is the original research paper on WiTricity: http://www.sciencemag.org/content/317/5834/83.short   Incidentally, the study cites 40% efficiency at a distance of about 2 meters. In wireless energy terms, that's pretty good.

Comment: @Droid Yes, your understanding is correct. I've added a case study to illustrate the differences in efficiency of an inductive system versus a wired system.

Comment: @RocketSurgeon that would be radiated EM, if you radiate in every direction chances are no more then .001% of your power will be picked back up. Beyond the fact that the best antenna in existence cannot do better then 50% pickup.

Comment: @RocketSurgeon: In fact a lot of that energy will go into space. While I'm not intimately familiar with Tesla's proposed invention, he probably failed to take into account the cost of producing enough electricity to make his ideas into reality.

Comment: Small directly coupled devices like your toothbrush and cell phone are totally different cases than what Tesla was trying to do and the OP is asking about.

Comment: Agree with @OlinLathrop here. The major difference is near field and far field. A far-field antenna that is interacting with 100% of your radiated power(which we know is impossible) and perfectly matched can not pick up more then half power. Long proof involved.

Comment: @OlinLathrop The OP also asked "why do we have to physically plug in our electrical devices (phones/computer, etc) if there exist such a thing as wireless electricity?" And also asked about limited range devices in the comments. My answer starts with limited range devices then mentions the MIT team's system and WiTricity as mentioned by Joel which work over several meters (still not Tesla scale). I then compare the drop in efficiency over the small change in available range between the two systems. There's more to the question than just the comic.

Comment: @Kortuk The question is about more than just Tesla's tower. It's about wireless electricity in general. And the OP specifically mentions limited range devices in a comment. There is absolutely a difference between near field and far field. What I tried to do here is compare the drop in efficiency between millimeter range devices and meter range devices. The question is broader than "Why no Tesla tower?" And the answer is more than just "Tesla's tower is stupid".

Comment: @embedded.kyle I think the implication to tesla and having to plug in with tesla's accomplishments might imply he thinks that nothing would need to be wired. Your answer is very nice, and I have upvoted you, but mentioning that this is only really feasible at all in near field is probably a valuable addition.

Comment: @Kortuk Well, that's not entirely true either when you take into account microwave and laser which can achieve much greater distances. I briefly mentioned this in my answer as did Olin in a comment above. But seeing as how this has become a pretty popular post, I have expanded my answer to (hopefully) better discuss the distance issue.

Comment: @Kortuk And just to be clear, I'm in no way angry about the criticism. I just felt the need to defend _the way_ in which I answered the question. I happen to agree with rawbrawb's points in [this meta discussion](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/2781/10045). I read the question as the OP saw the comic and became interested in wireless electricity _in general_, not Tesla's tower _in particular_. So I largely ignored the tower and gave real world examples of similar technology instead. The votes and green check seem to indicate that the community appreciated this approach.

Comment: @embedded.kyle I like the new answer! It has added what I want, sorry I cant give you more rep with a second upvote for a reward.

Comment: Is the law really exponential? I would have thought it would be an inverse-square law, like light, gravitation, etc.

Comment: @EJP I wouldn't call that a law. Just the results of one experiment. The reality is, of course, a bit more complex. Since radio waves can be used to transmit power or data, have a look at the [Friis Transmission Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation). The gains of the antennas and the wavelength/frequency also play a part.

Comment: @embedded.kyle The inverse-square law is a Law of Physics.

Comment: "by adding an RC network"  No.  You want R to be as minimal as possible.  You're using resonant LC circuits with very high Q (very low R) to couple with each other at a single very precise frequency.  And inductive resonance is still near-field, as I understand it.  Otherwise it would radiate and waste a lot of energy.  The antennas couple with each other in a way that makes the energy transfer directionally.

Comment: @endolith You are correct. I misspoke. I've edited to correct the statement.

Answer (score 11):

If you radiate power spherically (equal in all directions), power received at the other end will be proportional to the percentage of the sphere covered by the receiver.  The further away you get, the less energy you capture for the same size antenna, proportional to 1/r^2.  The rest of the energy is wasted into free space.  This is a massively oversimplified model, of course.  If you know where the receiver is you'd make the transmitter directional, use resonance etc., but you get the idea.  Wireless energy does not magically find its way to your receiver with 100% efficiency.  On top of that you have power conversion circuitry that isn't 100% efficient either.

If send & receive are millimeters apart and power levels are low, as in a toothbrush or phone dock, then efficiency is tolerable and the lost power doesn't cost much.  A toothbrush only costs pennies a year to keep charged, so trading off extra energy cost against waterproofing the product for a bathroom environment is worth it.  A pad under your electric car transmitting thousands of watts over a foot of ground clearance would waste tens of dollars a month in energy cost compared to plugging in.  Trying to run a clothes dryer directly from an electric company tower on top of a hill miles away simply wouldn't work.

We may yet see wireless or ambient power become popular for tiny embedded devices, such as a low-power microcontroller monitoring something.  If microcontroller power consumption gets low enough, it can run continuously from a tiny solar panel, a coil of wire as in an RFID badge, piezoelectric device or so on.  Energy could be harvested from WiFi signals, heat, mechanical movement, or other ways that are not used today because the power levels are too low to be useful.  Transmitting collected data over, say, Bluetooth LE takes much more energy than simply running the microcontroller, so the transmit bursts have to be short and infrequent, with some energy storage (capacitor) filling slowly in between.  This is the realm of microwatts or maybe nanowatts, so forget about having your cellphone continuously charged as you walk around.  Texas Instruments seems to be paying attention to energy harvesting if you want more information about it.

Comment: It's worth noting that AM radio sets that received their power wirelessly could for many years be purchased much more cheaply than those which used batteries or plugged into the wall.  One would have to hook them up to a very big antenna, and listen to them with earphones in an otherwise quiet room, but they worked and were relatively cheap.  The usefulness of such radios would be limited in many areas today because their tuners were not very selective, but the technology for radios to be powered wirelessly is hardly new.  Microcontrollers might need even less electricity than an earphone.

Comment: As I understand it, those AM radio sets demodulated audio from the carrier and sent it directly to the earpiece as an analog waveform with enough energy to mechanically move the earpiece diaphragm.  This is different from what we usually think of power today, as a regulated voltage supply that can output up to some level of current before falling out of regulation.  You might be able to harvest AM radio energy into some storage and regulate it, then power a microcontroller from it, but let's not forget about all that extra circuitry in the middle.

Answer (score 11):

The reason we don't distribute power as Tesla had tried is because it doesn't work.  It is basically a dumb idea because:

The power available in any fixed volume decreases with the cube of the distance from the transmitter.  Lets say for example that you could extract 100 kW from a cubic meter 10 meters from the transmitter.  At 100 meters that would be 100 W.  At 200 meters 12.5 Watts, which is barely enough to power a light.

There is no way to measure individual use, so how do you charge people?  You can't expect me to pay just because you put up a tower.  I can claim I never used any of the power, and you can't prove otherwise.

We don't really know what the health effects of long term exposure to significantly powerful electric fields are.  Think about it.  If a lightbulb is supposed to intercept the power from this field to light itself, how exactly is your body not supposed to intercept some power?

How do you keep ordinary object that happen to have the right electrical properties from intercepting the power and heating up?  You'd have to be very careful with using any material that isn't a good insulator.  You'd have to keep its size, orientation, and impedance in mind carefully to avoid it grabbing power from the E field all around it.  Think of all the metal objects you take for granted.  Even a aluminum can of soda could be a problem.

It is horribly inefficient, even if it did work.  There will be many ordinary object as in #4 above.  Let alone what happens to those objects when they intercept this power, but think of the huge waste of power from the producer's side.  Every wet tree branch, the ground, and all sorts of things will take power from this E field.

Like I said, it's dumb idea, and was a dumb idea when Tesla tried it too, as some of his own equations should have told him.

Comment: @DrFriedParts - #1 Then let's assume, quite reasonably that the power is distributed radially from the power station. Then you still have to suffer power density falling off as the square of the distance. Better than the cube, but much worse than a cable.

Comment: @DrFriedParts - #2 Detect and localise disturbances to E-fields for *thousands* of closely spaced customers surrounding the transmitter?

Comment: @DrFriedParts - #3 Oh really? There are studies where they have subjected large numbers of people to these *much* more powerful fields for several decades? No, of course not. You are probably thinking of much lower powered transmitters, like those used for phones and FM radio.

Comment: @DrFried: #1, no isotropic or not has nothing to do with it.  In any one direction, the power per area still falls of by the square of the distance and power per volume by the cube.  The power level will be higher in a focused beam (at the expense of other directions), but the falloff is still the same.

Comment: @DrFriedParts - #5 and indeed it *is* used in those cases where the inefficiency doesn't really matter as much as the convenience. But in the mains electricity industry where efficiency really matters, such a massive waste would be intolerable.

Comment: @DrFried: #2, No, certainly not with a single tower.  Note that to find the 3D distribution of the field you need multiple sensors.  To get any reasonable distribution would require *a lot* of sensors.  This would take lot of infrastructure, probably still wouldn't work well enough, but isn't what Tesla was trying to do in the first place.

Comment: @DrFried: #3 Show me just one study *at that power level*.  Perhaps we don't have proof it is dangerous, but we certainly don't have proof it's not.  This is a case where you need to know its safe before you subject whole neighborhoods, as Tesla intended, to *very powerful* electric fields.

Comment: @DrFried: #4 Cell phone towers don't heat doorknobs much since the power levels are so low. Then again, you can't light a lightbulb from RF power intercepted from cell towers as Tesla intended. We are talking about *vastly* larger power levels. A few nW or uW may be irrelevant, but a few W not.

Comment: @DrFried: #5 What you say is not relevant to what I was talking about. Wireless power transfer can be useful in some cases, but we are talking about neighborhood scale here. At utility-levels of power, efficiency matters, a lot. When you're sloshing around MW, a few percent suddenly becomes real money. When the business case is about selling energy, every bit of inefficiency is money lost. A few 100 Joules lost when charging a toothbrush is nothing, but 10s of kW continuously lost is a whole different issue, especially when you're selling kWh.

Comment: @DrFried: The OP specifically mentioned the Wardenclyffe Tower, and I specifically qualified my answer to "as Tesla had tried".  Yes there are other different schemes of wireless power transfer for small distances and with tight coupling, but I wasn't answering about that *as I stated in the answer*.  You are so eager to find fault that you didn't read the answer very well.  Also, saying the answer lacks understanding of radiative physics without citing particular objections is poor science (actually no science at all).

Comment: Look, this got pointless fast. We basically agree. We just interpret the scope of the question differently.

Comment: "The power available in any fixed volume decreases with the cube of the distance from the transmitter."  Tesla explicitly claimed that the system  did not depend on electromagnetic radiation, as in NBK's answer.  I don't know if "sending current energy through the earth" makes any sense, but you're just knocking down a straw man here.

Answer (score 3):

Counsel:

> Let's see if I understand this correctly.  If you have radiation or electromagnetic waves going from your system, the energy is wasted?

Tesla:

> Absolutely wasted.  From my circuit you can get either electromagnetic waves, 90 percent of electromagnetic waves if you like, and 10 percent in the current energy that passes through the earth.  Or, you can reverse the process and get 10 percent of the energy in electromagnetic waves and 90 percent in energy of the current that passes through the earth.
>
> It is just like this: I have invented a knife.  The knife can cut with the sharp edge.  I tell the man who applies my invention, you must cut with the sharp edge.  I know perfectly well you can cut butter with the blunt edge, but my knife is not intended for this.  You must not make the antenna give off 90 percent in electromagnetic and 10 percent in current waves, because the electromagnetic waves are lost by the time you are a few arcs around the planet, while the current travels to the uttermost distance of the globe and can be recovered.
>
> This view, by the way, is now confirmed.  Note, for instance, the mathematical treatise of Sommerfeld,[*] who shows that my theory is correct, that I was right in my explanations of the phenomena, and that the profession was completely misled.  This is the reason why these followers of mine in high frequency currents have made a mistake.  They wanted to make high frequency alternators of 200,000 cycles with the idea that they would produce electromagnetic waves, 90 percent in electromagnetic waves and the rest in current energy.  I only used low alternations, and I produced 90 percent in current energy and only 10 percent in electromagnetic waves, which are wasted, and that is why I got my results. . . .
>
> You see, the apparatus which I have devised was an apparatus enabling one to produce tremendous differences of potential and currents in an antenna circuit.  These requirements must be fulfilled, whether you transmit by currents of conduction, or whether you transmit by electromagnetic waves.  You want high potential currents, you want a great amount of vibratory energy; but you can graduate this vibratory energy.  By proper design and choice of wave lengths, you can arrange it so that you get, for instance, 5 percent in these electromagnetic waves and 95 percent in the current that goes through the earth.  That is what I am doing.  Or you can get, as these radio men, 95 percent in the energy of electromagnetic waves and only 5 percent in the energy of the current. . . . The apparatus is suitable for one or the other method.  I am not producing radiation with my system; I am suppressing electromagnetic waves. . . . In my system, you should free yourself of the idea that there is radiation, that the energy is radiated.  It is not radiated; it is conserved. . . .

Tesla was not stupid!

:)

Comment: But he was also wrong.